# App crashes when trying to add item to SQLite Database (onPause() error)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, onpause

I'm trying to make it so when I click a button it adds what is in my edit text to my SQLite table but when I click it, it just crashes. I'm getting an onpause error. Here is the log cat.

```
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree/com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3144)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1264)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog.saveState(ScheduleTweetDialog.java:266)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at com.oxpheen.tweetschedulerfree.ScheduleTweetDialog.onPause(ScheduleTweetDialog.java:262)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
11-20 20:06:32.076: E/AndroidRuntime(10548):    ... 13 more
```

Here's my onpause method

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState(); //Line 262 where it crashes
  }
```

And my saveState method

```
 private void saveState() {
    String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem(); //Line 266 where it crashes
    String summary = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String description = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    if (description.length() == 0 && summary.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put (TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category == null ? "" : category);
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, summary);
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

    if (todoUri == null) {
      // New todo
      todoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
      // Update todo
      getContentResolver().update(todoUri, values, null, null);
    }
  }
```

I'm really new to databases and what not, so I'm sorry if this is an easy error. But if you could help me that'd be great. Thank you so much. If you need any other code just tell me I will post immediately!

Comment: where is mCategory defined?  Where is it initialized?

Comment: public Spinner mCategory;    mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);            for (int i = 0; i < mCategory.getCount(); i++) {

            `String s = (String) mCategory.getItemAtPosition(i);
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(category)) {
              mCategory.setSelection(i);
            }
          }`   and then in the savestate method

Comment: ok, that is the definition.  Are you initializing it in onCreate()?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5MD66qhi   That's easier. And I believe so...

Comment: Try checking the value of mCategory in onCreate, i.e. "if (mCategory==null) .....".    All evidence point to this being the cause.

Comment: Like I said, I'm really new to databases so I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: could you post the layout file: res/layout/activity_schedule_tweet_dialog.xml as well?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Cvwfn1DX  I have this same thing working on my other class and it works flawlessly but what I'm trying to do here is just get the text from the mTitleText edit text and be able to click save so it adds it to the database. I don't want the category or the description added.

Comment: Your XML file does not contain a Spinner.  It does not contain any element with the id "category".  Thus mCategory will be null.  That is your problem.

Comment: I've tried adding it before but it still did the same thing.         `<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/priorities"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </Spinner>`

Comment: I got it to work! What I did was the mBodyDescription to the layout. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much for guiding me to that!!! Only spent 4 hours on this hahaha. Programming >>>

Comment: I'll promote my findings to an answer.  Please feel free to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null pointer is due to the fact that mCategory is null.  Based on the code you posted, your view does not contain a Spinner with the id "category".  That explains why getViewById(R.id.category) returned null.